# Formik + Yup accessing errors for nested values

Tags: node.js, reactjs, formik, yup

I am trying to use Formik and Yup together to validate my users data, but when I try and access errors of a nested value, such as `address.line1`, I get an error saying that it's undefined. How do I access the errors for a nested value with Formik and Yup?

See Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ly027lklq7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code, it seems like you're accessing the object wrong. Your conditionals were `errors.line1 && touched.address.line1`, but should be `errors.address && errors.address.line1 && touched.address.line1`.

Your error happened because errors.address does not exist at first as errors is an empty object at the start. You can check this by `console.log(errors)`.

I tried using this piece of code and it works. (https://codesandbox.io/s/4w83767610?fontsize=14)

```
<Form>
  <Field name="firstName" placeholder="first Name" />
    {errors.firstName && touched.firstName ? (
      <div>{errors.firstName}</div>
    ) : null}
    <br />

  <Field name="address.line1" placeholder="line 1" />
    // changed the conditional and object access
    {errors.address && errors.address.line1 && touched.address.line1 ? (
      <span className="red">{errors.address.line1}</span>
    ) : (
      ""
    )}
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</Form>
```